# Are the attribution requirements for the premium version of the Google Places API different?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

Are the attribution requirements for the premium version of the Google Places API different from the free one?

Specifically, does the premium version of the autocomplete version of the Places API require an attribution to Google to be shown ?

Answer (score 0):

This question can probably only be answered by [Google Maps API Sales](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/), best to ask them.

From what I could find, I suspect the answer will be Yes. See the [Google Maps API - Purchase Agreement](https://enterprise.google.com/maps/terms/us/maps_purchase_agreement.html) which apply on top of the more general [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_4).